# Outputting errors to browser in CherryPy

Tags: python, browser, logging, stack-trace, cherrypy

I am new to cherrypy, and can't seem to figure out how to have cherrypy emit a stacktrace or error message to my browser when an error occurs.

I am running cherrypy on apache with mod_wsgi, so its particularly annoying to dig through the  apache error logs during development.

I am used to PHP, where errors are nicely output to the browser when your script crashes. It is a useful feature when debugging. How does one do this in CherryPy?

This section on [logging in CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/Logging) doesn't seem to cover that, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most important config setting which governs tracebacks in the browser is [`request.show_tracebacks`](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/_cprequest.html#cherrypy._cprequest.Request.show_tracebacks). Set it to `True` to get tracebacks. Note that using the "production" [config environment](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/concepts/config.html#environments) sets this to `False`. There may be other WSGI components you're using, or some feature of mod_wsgi or Apache which is also getting in the way, but I can't speak to those.

Comment: The linked page in the answer no longer contains the {{show_tracebacks}} setting, which is confusing and meant that I had to manually test this out just to make sure that option was even still present.  Is that an intentional omission, or should I create a pull request for the documentation?